# Displaying jobs & job dates in sequence horizontally in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, calendar, jobs

I'm struggling to figure out the best method of displaying list of jobs, each contains a `start_date` and an `end_date`. A `Job` also contains an array of `down_days` where the Team was inactive. I've looked into a couple of gems [Simple Calendar](https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar) and the JS [Full-Calendar](http://fullcalendar.io) plugin which are both great, but not quite what I'm looking for. The Simple Calendar gem only shows the job/event for one day, not all the days from the `start_date` to the estimated `end_date`. I'm estimating the end_date of a job by other criteria in the model and have a scope for getting all the jobs for this week.

```
scope :active_jobs, -> { where( "current_stage < total_stages" ) }
scope :this_weeks_jobs, -> { where( "start_date <= ?", 1.week.from_now ) }
```

Currently, I'm getting getting an array of days containing all the days between the `start_date` and the `end_date`.

```
def job_days
  return ((self.start_date.to_date..self.estimate_end_date.to_date).to_a)
end
```

Ideally, the table head is a list of days of the week starting with the current day and then the job name in the column beneath. So, I need to be able to check and see if the `Job` is both active on each day shown as well as checking whether a `down_day` exists for that day. When I click a `Job`, it's details would show beneath. I've tried `group_by` but I haven't figured out how to check whether there's a `down_day` for each job instance on each job day.

```
@jobs = Job.active_jobs.this_weeks_jobs.includes(:team)
@grouped_jobs = @jobs.group_by(&:start_date)
```

I've also managed the table header of days of the week with:

```
@days = (Date.today..Date.today + 7.days).to_a
```

Then in the view, I'm probably **incorrectly,** doing:

```
<% @days.each do |d| %>
  <td><%= weekday_name(d) %> <%= d.strftime('%m/%d') %></td>
<% end %>

... unimportant html

<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <% job.job_days.each do |job_day| %>
    <td>
      <% if job.down_days.include?(job_day) %>
        <span class="down-day">Down Day</span>
      <% else %>
        <a href="#<%= job.job_id.parameterize %>" class="btn btn-primary" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="<%= job.job_id.parameterize %>" data-toggle="collapse"><%= job.job_id %></a>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

... more unimportant html & stuff
```

I'm likely going about this incorrectly and just need some guidance about how to create and display the days given the `start_date` and estimating the `end_date` and also taking into account the potential for one or more of the days being a `down_day`. Ideally, this would be like a weekly calendar except each `job` would be shown for each of the days it's active and not in the `down_days` array.

Here is the relevant attributes from the schema and the association info.

```
#Jobs
has_many :resources
belongs_to :team

t.string   "job_id"
t.integer  "total_stages"
t.integer  "current_stage"
t.datetime "start_date"
t.datetime "end_date"
t.datetime "down_days", default: [], array: true
t.integer  "team_id"
t.string   "status"


#Resources
belongs_to :team
belongs_to :job

t.string   "type"
t.string   "number"
t.integer  "team_id"
t.integer  "job_id"


#Team
belongs_to :region
has_many :jobs
has_many :resources

t.string   "name"
t.integer  "region_id"
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Comment: Please, show table structure of all models involved in your question (you may copy/paste from `schema.rb` file) and their relations to each other. Thank you.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the schema info and relationships. Let me know if anyone has any other questions, and thanks for any direction anyone may be able to offer.